# How to Set Visibility GONE for ImageView if URL is Empty?

Tags: android

I am using Image-loader programmatic in my Application, I want to hide my Image-view when There is no any image URL is coming. If I don’t allow to hide technique, Extra space is taken by List Row. How can I Hide this Image-view ? Please guide me..

```
openURl = data.get(position).getFile_icon_url();

if (openURl != null && !openURl.isEmpty()){
    KidSummary.imageLoader.displayImage(openURl, imageview, KidSummary.optionsItems);
}else {
    imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Which image loader you are using?

Comment: If this logic is in your ListView adapter, I think that the row already takes up space, I would loop over the ArrayList checking if URL is empty and if it is, remove it and than set adapter (*might be wrong*).

Comment: ImageLoader using programmatic bro... I am not using any Jar file

Comment: can you show the app flow?  i guess you are passing the data to adapter and then setting it.  and is there anything extra in data object other than a URI string

Comment: This code should hid the image view. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: why you are hiding imageview...user placeholder if image is coming empty

Comment: Need To see your row inflater because if you are not hide parent of imageview than that will occupy space and i think you are facing empty space on blank url right?

Answer (score -1):

You store the url data  in array list. Check your arraylist if arraylist is empty then hide your ImageView if arraylist is not empty then there is image and show it on your Imageview.`

For checking arraylist you have to set the bool  arraylist object for example object is arraylist  :

Everyday_fragment is object of arraylist.

```
boolean isCheck == false
if(Everyday_fragment.isEmpty())
            {
                isCheck = true;
            }
 if(isCheck == true)
{
hide your Imageview
}
else
{
show your ImageView
}
```